# How to add newly created item in line level through scripting?

Tags: netsuite

I'm creating item in estimate record and trying to add in line level through script, I can able to add for existing items which are created prior(either created through script or functionally) but I'm unable to add in line level for newly created item.

Item is getting created but not adding.

I guess this is because estimate record (page) is not refreshed.

Below is the sample code for adding item to line level after getting item id.
code is working fine for existing items.

```
var itemName=itemid;//getting item id after creating item
/*var itemName=275;*/ hard coding existing item
var amount=10;// hard coding amount
var stHtml = '<html>';

stHtml += '<head>';
stHtml += '<script language="JavaScript">';
stHtml += 'if (window.opener)';
stHtml += '{';
stHtml += 'window.opener.nlapiSetCurrentLineItemValue(\'item\', \'item\', \'' + itemName + '\', ' + false + ', ' + false + ');';
stHtml += 'window.opener.nlapiSetCurrentLineItemValue(\'item\', \'amount\', \'' + amount + '\', ' + false + ', ' + false + ');';
stHtml += 'window.opener.nlapiCommitLineItem(\'item\')';
stHtml += '}';
stHtml += 'window.close();';
stHtml += '</script>';
// stHtml+='<script type="text/javascript">' + confirm + '</script>';
stHtml += '</head>';
stHtml += '<body>';
// stHtml +='JavaScript:confirm();';
stHtml += '</body>';
// stHtml += '<body onload="JavaScript:confirm();"></body>';
stHtml += '</html>';

response.write(stHtml);
```

Comment: If you can get a record id when creating your item, that should be enough to add it as a line item. The select box for items uses AJAX requests to search for and find items, so should be able to find your item assuming it's been first saved. Do you have any more code of what you're trying to do?

Comment: But the record is not saved it is a fresh record so cant do that...Any how thanks i'm done with it......